# How to call a custom directive's action in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, kineticjs

In AngularJS you can make a button to call an action like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="onButtonClicked()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

So, I'm inserting a custom directive like this:

and in `my-canvas.js` directive file's link function I replace the tag with a `KineticJS` canvas. Then, User manipulate the canvas by dragging around `Kinetic` shapes and, finally, when User does with the shapes what he's required to do, I want the directive to call an action defined on `myController`. I'm thinking about something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <my-canvas ng-success="onScenarioSuccess" />
</div>
```

but I can't figure out how the correct way to do it.

How can I make a directive to call it's action/event programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

When you want your directive to expose an API for binding to behaviors you should use an isolate scope and use the `&` local scope property.  This allows you to pass in a function that the directive can invoke. Here is a simple example:

```
.directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            action: '&'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="action()">Test</button>'
    };
});
```

And use it like:

```
<test-directive action="myControllerFunction()"></test-directive>
```

As per the documentation:

> The `&` binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an
>   expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.
>   Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which
>   contains a function call. Because of this, `&` bindings are ideal for
>   binding callback functions to directive behaviors.

There'are some more detail in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a custom event like `ng-success` and want to call a function on the event.
You can either do what @Beyers has mentioned using isolated scope.

Or else look at the source code of `ng-click`, it just wraps the javascript event inside $scope.apply, using the `$parse` service to evaluate the expression passed to it. Something like this can be added in your link function

```
var fn = $parse(attr['ngSuccess']);
element.on('someEvent', function (event) {
    var callback = function () {
        fn(scope, {
            $event: event
        });
    };
    scope.$apply(callback);
});
```

The advantage of this mechanism is that isolated scope is not created.

Comment: Why is that an advantage? What do I lose by using an isolated scope?

Comment: Isolated scopes can become trickier to manage, when they have inner html. If the inner html comes from parent (ng-transclude) it takes parent scope. In inner html is the template html of directive then it takes the isolated scope. Isolated scopes make sense when you create your directive as component which has its own UI. If you are doing the same you can go ahead and use isolated scope.

Comment: @ErikEscobedo you dont lose anything by using an isolated scope, in fact you gain quite a bit. Isolated scope is all about reusability, in other words the directive does not rely on the parent scope to operate, nor are you able to accidentally change anything on the parent scope etc. Isolated scope is somewhat more complex to grasp initially, but IMHO is one of the core concepts to master to truly gain the benefits of directives. There are plenty of online material dedicated to this subject to get you up to speed.

Comment: As i said isolated scopes make sense when you are creating component directives, directives with their own view. If a directive is used like an extension to exiting directive or html element isolated scope can problematic. I do understand directives provide an isolation context that is helpful is some context. When you look at Angular directives too, you will notice none of them create isolated scope.